# DotNetNuke - Delete banner from bottom of blog post

Tags: dotnetnuke

In DotNetNuke, the blog posts have a control that has icons for facebook, google, Windows Live, etc. About ten icons total. The control also contains a list of tags, categories, trackback, and a print icon.

I want to remove the portion of the control with the 10 icons in it. How do I do this? Ideally, I want just the aforementioned control removed but I can live with the entire control, including the tags and categories parts, being deleted. I just don't know how to do that either. It doesn't appear to be a module.

What is the name of this control?
How do I delete it?
Looking for quick & dirty options for removing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is the default core DNN blog then there is actually a place in the module options to turn off the social bookmarks and most of the other elements you mention.

In the blog module - thats the one that displays the posts - go to module options and at the bottom of the list of options you will see the option to turn off the social bookmarks.